# permission denied while using tmux, screen or nohup

Tags: linux, openafs

Due to the afs token expiration, I want to have my jobs running in the background even when I log out.

I know of three options to accomplish this: `tmux`, `screen`, and `nohup`.

However, after I logged out and logged back in to check the job status, they are terminated due to permission denied errors when attempting to write into the files associated with the job. The weirdest thing is that this does not happen on all of the jobs but just a fraction of them.

What might be causing this? How can I figure out a solution to fix it?

Comment: Did you try sudo with these(nohup,...)

Comment: I am not the root user, so I might not be able to use this command